# Cannot resolve SVN tree conflicts

Tags: svn

I'm struggling to resolve a tree conflict when attempting to merge my branch into the trunk. I have the following SVN folder structure:

```
Project/
    branches/
        test1/
    tags/
    trunk/
```

The trunk was on r2958 when I did a svn copy to create my branch called test2. The branch test2 was created on r2975. So, now I have this:

```
Project/
    branches/
        test1/
        test2/
    tags/
    trunk/
```

Under the test1 branch, from r2868 to r3053, a new file was added and subsequently updated several times to get it into its final version. That was the only change in test1, which was merged into the trunk on r3055.

I wanted to update my test2 branch so it included the new file added under test1. So, I did a svn copy of just the new file from the trunk into test2. That revision is r3099.

Now, I'm done with the test2 branch and I want to merge, but I'm getting a tree conflict:

```
svn merge --dry-run -r2975:HEAD branches/test2 trunk
--- Merging r2976 through r3099 into 'trunk':
U    trunk/file1.docx
U    trunk/file2.docx
U    trunk/file3.docx
   C trunk/new_file_from_test1.docx
 G   trunk
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1
```

I've tried svn update, svn resolve, etc. but I can't figure out how to complete my merge. I am NOT using tortoiseSVN by the way (I'm on a Mac).

EDIT: Here are my steps to try and resolve the tree conflict:

```
svn up
Updating '.':
At revision 3099.

svn resolve --accept working trunk/new_file_from_test1.docx
[no output in terminal]

svn merge --dry-run -r2975:HEAD branches/test2 trunk
--- Merging r2976 through r3099 into 'trunk':
U    trunk/file1.docx
U    trunk/file2.docx
U    trunk/file3.docx
   C trunk/new_file_from_test1.docx
 G   trunk
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1
[same result]
```

I've also tried svn diff to get more info about the branch and trunk versions of the file, but I don't see any information...

```
svn info trunk/new_file_from_test1.docx | tail -n 4
Last Changed Date: 2022-10-05 15:12:01 -0400 (Wed, 05 Oct 2022)
Text Last Updated: 2022-10-05 15:11:04 -0400 (Wed, 05 Oct 2022)
Checksum: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

svn diff branches/new_file_from_test1.docx | tail -n 4
[no output in terminal]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you did something wrong when you made an `svn copy` of the added file from trunk to branch (apparently you were referring to branch test2, not test1).

Instead you should have done an *automatic sync merge*, aka [Keeping a Branch in Sync](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/branchmerge/basicmerging/#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.stayinsync).

Comment: I was able to fix the issue with the reintegrate flag. I'm not sure if that was the right thing to do or not, but it fixed the conflicts and I could complete my merge.

I tried the automatic sync merge link, and that's exactly what I'm looking for. I get in situations a lot where the trunk has been updated and I need those changes in my branch. I'll remember to use that next time. Thank you!